# timeout error debugging PHP with Eclipse PDT + Zend Server

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-framework, eclipse-pdt

I checked a lot of resources on line and tutorials but I was not able to solve, so I hope someone can help me.... I'm so frustrated about debugging php app with Eclipse PDT + Zend Server free edition.

I have a Zend Server free edition installed, and if I'm right it embeds directly Zend Debugger.
running phpinfo() command I can see a Zend Debugger section:
https://www.diigo.com/item/image/2kz5e/mjri

then on PDT side, I checked my configuration and it seems to be ok:
https://www.diigo.com/item/image/2kz5e/ix6e

Now if I try to debug a php web page it does not stop at breakpoints and if I click on "Test" button on the Zend Debugger run page inside Eclipse, it show me this error:
"A timeout occurred when the debug server attempted to connect the following client hosts/IPs:-127.0.0.1"

I can't understand what I missed.
Please help me!!!

Best regrads,
Matt